# Custom Behavior at UITableView Accessory cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, tableview

I need to implement a custom behavior in my uitableView Accessory Cell, the behavior is equals the behavior at iOS mail, and WhatsApp. With bounce and animations

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` where you can grab the indexpath of the row that was selected and do appropriate work.

For the animations you can use UIView animation blocks, or even animate over bezier paths.